# Disable "Get more out of windows" notification screen after login

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I've been searching online for a few weeks on how to disable the "Get more out of windows" popup screen that happens after the user logs in but before the desktop loads but everything I've been finding online has not worked. Turning all the notifications off does not work and the settings they are saying in the registry are not found. Has anyone found a way to disable this popup?

One site I tried is the following, but nothing here is working and the popup still comes up after a few days.

https://www.ghacks.net/2019/08/09/how-to-disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-on-windows-10/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to download Winaero Tweaker (https://winaero.com/) and disable telemetry altogether. That way, you wouldn't get any more of those notifications. The same editor has other advice linked to what you want to achieve here: https://winaero.com/blog/disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-in-windows-10/

Comment: The screen just happens once at first log in.  Make a screen shot, mark what users should and should not accept. Then leave it by computers that have multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

Disable that nag with the Settings app

Go to Settings > System > Notifications & actions

Find the checkbox which says “Show me the Windows welcome experience after updates and occasionally when I sign in to the highlight what’s new and suggested”

Uncheck the box

Close the Settings application.

Comment: I have done this but the notice is still coming up after a few days.

Comment: Is Windows _activated-; have you entered your License Key? If you haven't, Microsoft will keep nagging you and functions like this won't work right.